LinearGradientBrush for Polygon Stroke doesn't work
I have simple ContentPage with Polygon, I want to create Polygon.Stroke with gradient from Red to Green to White, but my stroke is only Red.
This what I am tring:
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage">

    <Polygon 
         Points="10,0 70,0 40,60"
         StrokeThickness="5">
        <Polygon.Stroke>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1" >
                <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="0.5"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Polygon.Stroke>
    </Polygon>

</ContentPage>

I hope you can easy reproduce my problem.

This is an known issue on the repo: GradientBrushes are not supported on Shape.Stroke. You can follow up it on the github.
In addtion, according to the pull request: Added a support for GradientBrushes on Shape.Stroke: this is still not fixed on the windows platform.
